# Git shortlog, case insensitive and file stat search

Tags: git, search, logging

I looking for a way to query the git log to list the number of edited (added, updated, deleted) files where the commit message matches a specific entry. I have started with this command....

`git shortlog --grep="searchtopic"`

1) How do I specify the grep searchtopic to be case insensitive (grepping SEARCHTOPIC, searchtopic and Searchtopic) and 2) also apply the the Commit stats: files changed, lines added, lines deleted (total) summary ?

Answer (score 16):

The `--grep` argument is handled the same way as in `git log`, so as with `git log`, use `-i` (also spelled `--regexp-ignore-case`) to ignore case.

If by "commit stats" you mean the short statistics that `git log --stat` prints, `git shortlog` does not support those at all.  Since it's rather literally *using* (the code of) `git log`, it takes the `--stat` argument just fine, but omits the statistics.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to improve the command `git log --grep="searchtopic" -i --oneline --shortstat`. Is it possible to summarise the stats in the end, to get total files changed, lines added/deleted?

Comment: The `--stat` output is only available *per commit*; if you want a summary by user, you'd have to read all the commits selected, compute (or have Git compute) their `--stat`s, and sum them. But note that if commit X adds 1000 lines and commit Z deletes 1000 lines, they could very well be the *same* 1000 lines: do you *want* to count both sets of lines?

Comment: Tracking the total amount of files changed will do, tracking lines added and deleted could not necessary in this case.

Comment: I was looking for the insensitive way of doing `git grep` and `-i` works too, thanks